# updating precalculated summary table

Tags: mysql

So i have a table for which i need to calculate some summaries(status and region are columns in this table) due to non mysql reason best solution i have come up with so far is to precalculate the summary and store it into a summary table , so below is basically a pre calculated table stored into the database

```
status/region  |    b1 |    b2 |    b3 | total
-----------------------------------------------
    a1         |    4  |    6  |    2  |  12
    a2         |    2  |    0  |    8  |  10
    total      |    6  |    6  |    10 |  22
```

So if lets say someone inserts something into the actual database with status a1 and region b1 while updating the original database i would also increment the count for it and increment both the totals.

it is sort of ok with insert but with update lets say he changed a1 b1 to a2 b2 i would have to do 6 updates here first 3 decrements for the count and the totals and then 3 increments for the other count and totals.

is there a better solution

Comment: I am afraid this is bassically a terrible idea! Summaries/totals stored on the database will basically always be at best a pain to maintain and normally next to impossible. **Something somewhere will always get forgotten!** It is a far better idea to write a query that generates this data that you can run when you want to see this data

Comment: There might be reasons to do a summary table (especially if a query to calculate that would take minutes or hours). Not shure about that here. You could try to use a trigger on the database to automatically regenerate the summary table. But it depends on how often inserts/updates are done. And if the summary table needs to be up-to-date all the time.

Comment: @Seb But remember, at least some hosting packages dont allow things like triggers